# Sum of squares of numbers equals product of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> Find number of tuples such that the sum of the squares of the numbers equals the product of the numbers.

I tried it and found some tuples like $(3,3,3)$ satisfying $3^2+3^2+3^2=3\times 3\times 3$ 
 but I don't know the real approach to find all such numbers. Can anyone try it?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There are infinite if you include $1$'s, e.g. $(1,1,\dots,1,4,4,4)$ with 16 $1$'s.

Comment: ooooh yes thanks a lot.I understood

Comment: but i wanted to see if there are more of these kind excluding one's.Like u can use 4 2's

Comment: You mean all tuples elements are equal, like $(x,x,x,...)$?

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please? Where did you come across it?

Comment: no they can be different like (6,3,3) and so on.I wanted to see how many solutions exist for this

Comment: That's what I thought you were going for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,I though it on my own and wanted to find numbers of this kind.I just like trying new problems

Comment: so are you sure @player3236 that iw would have infinite solutions and can you try to find the solutions excluding one's

Comment: "I just like trying new problems." So, why post it here? Isn't it more fun to work on it on your own?

Comment: @GerryMyerson,i tried it for 3 days and i couldnt get a proper solution of it.So i wanted to find a proper solution.

Comment: i think the answer is infinite as we can take  a number such that n^3=3n^2+x.Here for example we can make 4*4*4=4^2+4^2+4^2+(16) and this 16=x which can be made using 1's and n=2q form.

Comment: This problem is too wide and should have more constraints.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, just to set the ball rolling on this question. As written in the comments the question is too open for a complete answer. This answer is limited to pairs and triples of numbers.

1. There are no numbers such that $a^2+b^2=ab$ (except the trivial solution $0,0$). A quick way to see this is $ab=a^2+b^2\ge2ab\ge ab$ so $a,b=0$.
2. If $a^2+b^2+c^2=abc$ then all three numbers must be divisible by $3$. Otherwise if $a=b=c=\pm1\pmod{3}$ then the LHS is divisible by $3$ but not the RHS. More generally, if $m$ divides any pair, say $a,b$, then it must divide the other, $c$. In fact, let $3m$ be the gcd of $(a,b,c)$, with $a=3mA$, $b=3mB$, $c=3mC$, so $$A^2+B^2+C^2=3mABC$$ In this form, no pair can have common factors (if $p|A,B$ then $p^2|C^2$), so all $A,B,C$ consist of distinct primes; also $m$ is not even.
   In fact there are an infinite number of solutions with $C=1$ $$A^2+B^2+1=3AB$$ Take any integer solutions of $x^2-5y^2=-4$ (there are an infinite number of these from the theory of quadratic forms). Then $A=\frac{3y\pm x}{2}$, $B=y$, $C=1$, satisfy the above equation, corresponding to the solutions of the original problem $$(3A)^2+(3B)^2+3^2=(3A)(3B)3$$ Thus there are an infinite number of such solutions. The first few combinations for $(A,B,C)$ are $(1,1,1)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(5,2,1)$, $(13,5,1)$, $(34,13,1)$, $(89,34,1)$, $(233,89,1)$, $(610,233,1)$, etc.

Some other observations:

- If a prime power $p^k$ divides $A$ say, then it also divides $B^2+C^2=A(3mBC-A)$. The [sum of squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) implies that $p=2$ or $p=1\pmod{4}$; $p=3\pmod{4}$ cannot divide $A$ only, else $B^2+C^2=0\pmod{p}$.
- If $A$ is even, then $B,C$ are odd; but $B^2+C^2$ is not divisible by $4$, so $A$ is not divisible by $4$. Thus either exactly one of $A,B,C$ is divisible by $2$ or none are.
- For each prime $p=1\pmod{4}$, one can solve the problem $A^2+B^2+p^2=3pAB$ using a similar approach as above. Solve $x^2-(9p^2-4)y^2=-4p^2$; then take $A=\frac{3py\pm x}{2}$, $B=y$, $C=p$.